# google sheet importxml returns error: imported content is empty

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am attempting to import data from website using the google sheet importxml function:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://decksofkeyforge.com/decks?title=Rych%C5%82y%20Mag","//div[@class='MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-h3']")
```

I am trying to get the sas raitng, one number circled on the image:
[54](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZX5xw.jpg)

Unfortunetely, the function returns error. It is my first time using it and I would like to ask if i am doing something wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you won't have any success, as the site you're trying to pull content from needs javascript to build - thus the node will probably not be accessible to `IMPORTXML`...
Try just pulling `=IMPORTXML("https://decksofkeyforge.com/decks?title=Rych%C5%82y%20Mag","//body")` and all you'll get will be a script tag and warning that you need to have JS enabled for the site to work.

Other than that, I can tell you that you have a slip up in your XPATH string, because you're trying to select a `h3` node, not `div` :)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is required to display the data. But you can get it from the `JSON` loaded in the background.

The easiest way to do it (other option is to write a `GoogleAppScript` to `POST` a request and retrieve the `JSON`) is to use `IMPORTDATA`, `QUERY` and `REGEXEXTRACT` formulas.

First, you have to gather the urls returned by the search engine. Those who contain the id of each deck (not the ones containing `decks?title=`). With your example : `https://decksofkeyforge.com/decks/111a6473-83cb-4b13-aa65-fbfb8ca7af37`.

Once you get them, you have to transform them with the following formula. In C3 :

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B3;"m/decks";"m/api/decks/with-synergies")
```

Then, use the following formula to extract the `sasRating`. In D3 :

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTDATA(C3));"select * WHERE Col1 starts with 'sasRating'";0);"\d+")*1
```

Output :

[image: SasRating]